# How to select an option form the non Select dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

URL: https://www.service-public.fr/simulateur/calcul/Dates_Vacances_Scolaires

I desperately try to select a department with selenium, for example **06 - Alpes-Maritimes** so that I can finally choose the school year by finally recovering the dates, but unfortunately I can't find the right method, I access the select and option but despite many try nothing happens "Element not be scrolled into view" then if someone can help me it's cool.

```
sel = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Departement']")
sel.send_keys('06 - Alpes-Maritimes')
sel.submit
```

Comment: Can you add enough code that we can reproduce what you're doing - i.e., the imports, the code that fetches the page, every needed so I can cut and paste your code on my machine and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clickable element with text as **06 - Alpes-Maritimes** is within a `<div>`

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="06 - Alpes-Maritimes" data-value="9">
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

[image: Alpes]

---

### Solution

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.service-public.fr/simulateur/calcul/Dates_Vacances_Scolaires")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#AutocompletionListbox-Departement"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.autocomplete-suggestions div[data-val$='Alpes-Maritimes']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.service-public.fr/simulateur/calcul/Dates_Vacances_Scolaires")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='AutocompletionListbox-Departement']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='autocomplete-suggestions ']//div[contains(@data-val, 'Alpes-Maritimes')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: maritimes]

Comment: Thank you very much for your high-quality assistance. I had started looking into EC, but I still haven't fully grasped how it works. A big thank you as well for sharing your knowledge and providing learning resources. I don't have enough points to add +1 to your answer, sorry.